# swift background BLE scanning with scanForPeripheralsWithServices UUID not taken into account

Tags: swift2, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm performing a BLE devices scan in a specific thread. but if I want my app to run in background, I need to specify to scanForPeripheralsWithServices a specific range of services.

when launching the following (with nil) :

```
func startScanning() {
    print("Start scanning...")
       if let central = centralManager {
            central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
        }
}
```

I can find my BLE device with UUID "B737D0E7-AF53-9B83-E5D2-922140A92E00", but as apple documentation mentioned it cannot be ruined as it is in background mode.

Then if I specify this UUID to the function:

```
func startScanning() {
    print("Start scanning...")
       if let central = centralManager {
            let ble = [CBUUID(string: "B737D0E7-AF53-9B83-E5D2-922140A92E00")]
            central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(ble, options: nil)
        }
}
```

scan is never called. do I miss something ?

Comment: do you need more details to help me ?

Comment: Sorry but I 'm not able to find a solution... Is there anybody who can help me?